# Many JSON request in same connection

Tags: java, json, session, urlconnection

I need to execute more than 1 JSON request, but I can't close my current connection

example code:

```
private String[] test(URL url, final URL url2) throws IOException {
    String[] test = new String[2];
    URLConnection openConnection = url.openConnection();
    test[0] = this.formatJSON(openConnection.getInputStream());
    url = url2;
    test[1] = this.formatJSON(openConnection.getInputStream());

    return test;
}
```

or

```
private String[] test(URL url, final URL url2) throws IOException {
    String[] test = new String[2];
    URLConnection openConnection = url.openConnection();
    test[0] = this.formatJSON(openConnection.getInputStream());
    url.setNewURL(url2);
    test[1] = this.formatJSON(openConnection.getInputStream());

    return test;
}
```

Any options?

Comment: What does that formatJSON method do? Are you reading in it all available input from inputStream?

Comment: I already solved the issue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

To execute more than one json request in the same session I just need to save the cookies from the first and then use him with the others.

this link helped me http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.htm